# Email with complex content and multiple attachment openapi 3.0

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I need an example for an email with some complext content(json format) and multiple array attachment. The attachments should be able to be of any format. so far I have searched everywhere and I am starting to think it may not be possible. what I would like is something like below:

```
/somepath:
put:
  summary: sends an email
  description: Send an email
  operationId: send-mail
  requestBody:
    content:
      multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/data.SomeData'
          type: object
          properties:
            format: binary
            attachment:
              content: 
                multipart/form-data:
                  schema:
                  properties:
                  my-attachment:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      type: string
                      format: binary
```

This is what I have tried to do in swagger 2.0, which looks more realistic and swagger 2.0 does not accept:

```
 /somePath:
put:
  consumes:
    - multipart/form-data
  description: Send an email
  operationId: send-mail
  parameters:
    - description: The Data model
      in: body
      name: someData
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/data.someData'
        type: object
    - description: Base 64 upload attachment
      in: formData
      name: file
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
        format: binary
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer for Openapi 3.0 :

```
multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            body:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/data.SomeData'
            file:
              type: array
              description: Base 64 upload attachment
              items:
                type: string
                format: binary
          required:
            - body
```